# vb.net process start Application not show up

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-7, windows-10

i face an error when using process.start in windows 10, the function is working in my windows 7, but not working in windows 10, the code of the button as below

```
Dim PDFFilePath As String = "C:\1.pdf"
Process.Start(PDFFilePath)
```

i had recorded the short video

Windows 10 Video

```
https://sendvid.com/i8w8q8nm
```

Windows 7 Video

```
hhttps://sendvid.com/as3lkm1g
```

From the task manager, i can see that process is started, but i cant found the windows from my screen

Comment: We don't know anything about the context where those two lines of code are being run. What kind of application is it? Where are you putting those lines of code? We need a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. Two lines of code with no other details is not sufficient.

Comment: the 2 line is the code of the button, it will open pdf file once button clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 uses it's app by default to read pdfs.

Change the default program for pdfs to acroboat reader or specify

```
Dim PDFFilePath As String = "C:\1.pdf"
Dim adobeAcrobatLocation as String = "..wherever.."
Process.Start(adobeAcrobatLocation, PDFFilePath)
```

Comment: but from the task manager, we can see the adobe reader is running, but we cant see the adobe reader window from screen